# Add comment outside of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to make a comment outside of my Wordpress blog but still using the moderation and CMS system?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to accomplish. I, for one, can't make sense of it at all. Do you want to use **a** wordpress install to manage comments, or **the** backend of your current blog? What does "outside of my Wordpress blog" mean - same domain, same server, entirely somewhere else? Comment on what, if not a wordpress post?

Comment: Well, basically I want to find a CMS that has the functionalities of Wordpress but the front-end is Flash. Therefor the inquiry of being able to add comments from outside of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

What you want to do is call wp-blog-header.php and then WP functionality will be available.

Comment: Do NOT add `wp-blog-header.php` to your site unless you have already made the WordPress core changes to support it.  Including this file causes WordPress to load a 404 header on the document, but build it anyways, meaning you get a silent "Page Not Found" for all the Search Engine web crawlers.

You want to use this code:
`define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/wordpress-folder/wp-load.php');`

Comment: @TbWill4321: Your comment simply repeats the correct way to use wp-blog-header. Read the docs at the link I posted. This method does not send a 404 header.

Comment: There is a number of pages on the web that document this behavior, including this correct answer on SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693341/how-does-including-wp-blog-header-php-change-the-file-location/9703866#9703866